# How to make stacked bar chart in Chartisan

Tags: laravel, chartjs-2.6.0, laravel-charts

I have laravel application and i want to display a chart. I have install Laravel Chart and Chartisan/Chartjs. But i dont know how to configure stacked bar.

```
@section('customScript')
<script>
  const chart = new Chartisan({
    el: '#chart',
    url: "@chart('application_by_state_chart')",
    hooks: new ChartisanHooks()
        .colors(['#ECC94B', '#4299E1'])
        .responsive()
        .beginAtZero()
        .legend({ position: 'bottom' })
        .title('This is a sample chart using chartisan!')
   });
 </script>
 @endsection
```

Comment: What is the issue, there is so much that it could be. The questions is still very vague. With the little amount of info given I would say check out the docs at https://charts.erik.cat/ and https://chartisan.dev/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the vague question, actually i just want to make customization on my graph as i am using chartisan with chartjs plugin. I have go through the documentation once again and found out there is something called custom hooks. The link below is what im trying to do using custom hooks because chartisan documentation did not specify how to use custom hooks.

https://github.com/Chartisan/Chartisan/issues/7#issuecomment-774745067